# Why does my Database not exist in the Main-Activity, when I return back to MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

in the Mainclass Im creating a variable called mDatabase. In the Mainclass there is a button called Database. When I click on it, it opens a new Activity. Then it starts the onCreate-Method of the second class databasegrocery.

When the program executes the command:

```
mAdapter=new GroceryAdapter(this, activity.getAllItems());
```

(...) it returns back to Main-Activity to call the method getAllItems().
When im returning to this method, mDatabase is null (mDatabase was already declared and initialized, when the app started with the MainActivity), why?

As Im totally new to android programing its possible that Im trying something stupid,
so I appreciate your help.

(I read something about activity-lifecycles and I saw that the MainActivity is in Stop-Status, when the second Activity is active. So the data from MainActivity is not destroyed, right?)

If you need more information, tell me!

Thank you.

```
package com.example.grocerylist;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    public SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
    private EditText mEditTextName;
    private EditText mEditTextName2;
    private EditText mEditTextName3;
    private EditText mEditTextName4;
    private EditText mEditTextName5;
    private EditText mEditTextName6;
    private EditText mEditTextName7;
    private EditText mEditTextName8;
    private EditText mEditTextName9;


    Button buttonIncrease;
    Button buttonDecrease;
    Button buttonAdd;
    Button buttonDatabase;
    public databasegrocery database;

    Intent IntentDatabase;

    private TextView mTextViewAmount;
    private int mAmount = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        GroceryDBHelper dbHelper = new GroceryDBHelper(this);
        mDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        mEditTextName = findViewById(R.id.edittext_name);
        mTextViewAmount = findViewById(R.id.textview_amount);

        mEditTextName2=findViewById(R.id.edittext_name2);
        mEditTextName3=findViewById(R.id.edittext_name3);
        mEditTextName4=findViewById(R.id.edittext_name4);
        mEditTextName5=findViewById(R.id.edittext_name5);
        mEditTextName6=findViewById(R.id.edittext_name6);
        mEditTextName7=findViewById(R.id.edittext_name7);
        mEditTextName8=findViewById(R.id.edittext_name8);
        mEditTextName9=findViewById(R.id.edittext_name9);
        IntentDatabase=new Intent(MainActivity.this,databasegrocery.class);

        buttonIncrease = findViewById(R.id.button_increase);
        buttonDecrease = findViewById(R.id.button_decrease);
        buttonAdd = findViewById(R.id.button_add);
        buttonDatabase=findViewById(R.id.buttonDatabase);


        buttonDatabase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(IntentDatabase);
            }
        });



        buttonIncrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                increase();
            }
        });

        buttonDecrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                decrease();
            }
        });

        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addItem();
            }
        });
    }

    private void increase() {
        mAmount++;
        mTextViewAmount.setText(String.valueOf(mAmount));
    }

    private void decrease() {
        if (mAmount > 0) {
            mAmount--;
            mTextViewAmount.setText(String.valueOf(mAmount));
        }
    }

    private void addItem() {

        if (mEditTextName.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 || mAmount == 0) {
            return;
        }
        String name = mEditTextName.getText().toString();

        String mkcal1 = mEditTextName2.getText().toString();
        String mkcal2=mEditTextName3.getText().toString();
        String mFett=mEditTextName4.getText().toString();
        String mDavongesaettigtefettsaueren=mEditTextName5.getText().toString();
        String mKohlenhydrate=mEditTextName6.getText().toString();
        String mZucker=mEditTextName7.getText().toString();
        String mEiweiss=mEditTextName8.getText().toString();
        String mSalz=mEditTextName9.getText().toString();
        //___________________________________________________________________

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(GroceryContract.GroceryEntry.COLUMN_NAME, name);
        cv.put(GroceryContract.GroceryEntry.COLUMN_AMOUNT, mAmount);

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        cv.put(GroceryContract.GroceryEntry.COLUMN_KCAL1, mkcal1);
        cv.put(GroceryContract.GroceryEntry.COLUMN_KCAL2, mkcal2);
        cv.put(GroceryContract.GroceryEntry.COLUMN_FETT, mFett);
        cv.put(GroceryContract.GroceryEntry.COLUMN_DAVONGESAETTIGTEFETTSAEUREN, mDavongesaettigtefettsaueren);
        cv.put(GroceryContract.GroceryEntry.COLUMN_Kohlenhydrate, mKohlenhydrate);
        cv.put(GroceryContract.GroceryEntry.COLUMN_Zucker, mZucker);
        cv.put(GroceryContract.GroceryEntry.COLUMN_EIWEIS, mEiweiss);
        cv.put(GroceryContract.GroceryEntry.COLUMN_SALZ, mSalz);

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


        mDatabase.insert(GroceryContract.GroceryEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        databasegrocery.mAdapter.swapCursor(getAllItems());

        mEditTextName.getText().clear();
        mEditTextName2.getText().clear();
        mEditTextName3.getText().clear();
        mEditTextName4.getText().clear();
        mEditTextName5.getText().clear();
        mEditTextName6.getText().clear();
        mEditTextName7.getText().clear();
        mEditTextName8.getText().clear();
        mEditTextName9.getText().clear();
    }



    public Cursor getAllItems() {
        return mDatabase.query(GroceryContract.GroceryEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, GroceryContract.GroceryEntry.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " ASC");
    }


}
```

```
package com.example.grocerylist;


import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class databasegrocery extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static GroceryAdapter mAdapter;
    public MainActivity activity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.databasegrocery);

        activity=new MainActivity();

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mAdapter = new GroceryAdapter(this, activity.getAllItems());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);



    }

}
```

Comment: "When im returning to this method, mDatabase is null (mDatabase was already declared and initialized, when the app started with the MainActivity), why?" – The `mDatabase` field was initialized in the `MainActivity` instance that was created by the system when it was launched. When you do `new MainActivity()` in `databasegrocery`, that is a new, completely different instance than the one that's already running. Furthermore, you cannot instantiate `Activity` classes yourself, and have them work correctly. The system must handle that; otherwise, they're not initialized and cycled properly,...

Comment: ...so `onCreate()` never runs, and all of those fields are never assigned. You don't need a `MainActivity` instance to use `GroceryDBHelper` in `databasegrocery`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!